# Does graph call driveitem-permanentdelete also prohibits secondary recycle bin restores?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, delete-file

**Purpose of the question**

I want to *validate* the following:

**API call performed**

If i call: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-permanentdelete?view=graph-rest-1.0

This will permanently delete the document as described in the documentation.

**Question:**

Does this also mean permanently for the secondary recycle bin ? (assuming yes but just to know for sure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you presumption is correct, it's a permanent delete and file is not accessible from second stage recycle bin.

You can check the second stage recycle bin

```
https://{tenant_name}.sharepoint.com/sites/{site_name}/_layouts/15/RecycleBin.aspx?view=13
```